# Line Break with mhchem

Tags: line-breaking, mhchem

I use the `mhchem` package for setting chemical formulas. In some occasions the formula just hangs over the end of the line. Is there any solution to fix this?

```
Für die Abscheidung von \ce{Al2O3} werden als Reaktionsmittel Trimethylaluminium (\ce{C6H18Al2}) und Wasser (\ce{H2O}) verwendet.
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Sample Picture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for `sloppypar`.  The first paragraph doesn't have it, the 2nd does.

The downside of "sloppy" is excessive inter-word space on the 1st line of the 2nd paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\textwidth 5.5in
\usepackage{mhchem,lipsum}
\begin{document}
Für die Abscheidung von \ce{Al2O3} werden als Reaktionsmittel Trimethylaluminium (\ce{C6H18Al2}) und Wasser (\ce{H2O}) verwendet. \lipsum[1]

\begin{sloppypar}
Für die Abscheidung von \ce{Al2O3} werden als Reaktionsmittel Trimethylaluminium (\ce{C6H18Al2}) und Wasser (\ce{H2O}) verwendet. \lipsum[1]
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Rewording

I'm not sure what you want LaTeX to do. Ideally, you would reword the text so that LaTeX would be able to properly justify the text.

### Why the Formula Hangs Over

The fact that LaTeX allowed the formula to hang over the right margin indicates that it was not able to find a way to fit the formula into the text the way it was worded; it is impossible for LaTeX to properly typeset the text without *breaking typographical specifications*.

Logically, the formula `(\ce{C6H18Al2})` is either **(case 1)** forced on the first (printed) line or **(case 2)** allowed to move to the second printed line. **Case 1:** If `(\ce{C6H18Al2})` is on the first line, then there isn't enough room to fit all the material in the line, so `(\ce{C6H18Al2})` must hang over. **Case 2:** If `(\ce{C6H18Al2})` is on the second line, then the first line doesn't have enough words to fill the entire line (putting only `Für die Abscheidung von \ce{Al2O3} werden als Reaktionsmittel Trimethylaluminium` on a single line would cause too much space between the words with full justification.)

## Forcing a Line Break

The other option, which is not typographically preferable, is to force a line break and allow LaTeX to justify the text before the line. Note that this will lead to excessive spacing between the words. The `\linebreak` command accomplishes this (it causes the line to be stretched accordingly).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
Für die Abscheidung von \ce{Al2O3} werden als Reaktionsmittel Trimethylaluminium
\linebreak (\ce{C6H18Al2}) und Wasser (\ce{H2O}) verwendet. Das Trägergas für die
Reaktionsmittel ist Distickstoffmonoxid (\ce{N2O}). Der Abscheidungsprozess kann
in vier Schritte eingeteilt werden.
\end{document}
```

[image: Use of \linebreak]